# Auth0 connecting to Azure AD is not returning my state params

Tags: azure, auth0, azure-active-directory

Using auth0, I'm following this tutorial about connecting a multi-tenant saas to Azure AD:
https://auth0.com/docs/tutorials/building-multi-tenant-saas-applications-with-azure-active-directory

But, since my case is a bit different, I need it to pass some parameters when the user logs in. For the other connections, I'm able to set options.authParams.state = "..." and this state is sent to my callbackURL.

But, using Azure AD connection, my state variable is not correct. It's empty when I receive the callback.

I'm including the new Azure AD button according to the tutorial:

```
lock.once('signup ready', function () {
                    var link = $('<div class="a0-zocial a0-icon a0-waad" href="#">'
                        + '<span>Azure AD</span></div>');
                    link.on('click', function () {
                        lock.getClient().login({ 
                            connection: 'seedtec-onmicrosoft-com'
                        });
                    });

                    var iconList = $(this.$container).find('.a0-iconlist');
                    iconList.append(link);
                });
```

And sending my state through options:

```
var options = {
                    container: 'root'
                  , callbackURL: 'http://.../LoginCallback.ashx'
                  , responseType: 'code'
                  , dict: 'pt'
                  , socialBigButtons: false
                  , authParams: {
                      state: state
                      , scope: 'openid profile'
                      , company_id: $scope.companyId
                  }
                  , mode: mode
                  , callbackOnLocationHash: true
                };



lock.show(options);
```

Do you know what is wrong in that?

Thank you!

PS: I'm using angular libraries for auth0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out the solution to this. It was quite simple, but it's not well documented by auth0.

When calling `lock.getClient().login(...)` I had to pass the authparams again like this:

```
lock.getClient().login({
    connection: 'myconn-onmicrosoft-com'
    , scope: 'openid profile'
    , company_id: 'blah...'
    , state: 'blah blah...'
});
```